# MIPS struct node

Tags: c, assembly, mips

The following linked list node is declared in C:

```
struct node {
  double val;
  struct node *next;
}
```

​Suppose that no more than 20 link nodes are needed for a problem. What are MIPS statements to reserve 20-node space for the linked list?

Comment: As with your other questions, please edit this one with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in C and check the resulting assembly generated by the C compiler. Anyway...

Double-precision floating point -> 64 bits

Pointer -> 32 bits

Total struct size -> 96 bits + 32 bits to align doubles -> 128 bits

20 structs + 1 head list pointer (assuming it's a simple list with only one pointer to the starting element) -> 20 x 128 + 32 = 2592 bits

```
.space 2592
```

Comment: There is likely another 32 bits per structure to ensure that the 64 bit doubles are aligned on a 64 bit boundary, so there will be 128 bits per structure.

Comment: I think this depends on what MIPS version we're talking about, but yes, you're right.